# How to use F# TypeProvider to read PowerBall csv?

Tags: f#, f#-data

The powerball schema and separators are not consistent which makes it an unusual file to read. (http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt)

Sample:

`Draw Date  WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB  PP
09/24/2016  15  07  29  41  20  22  2
09/21/2016  63  67  01  69  28  17  4
09/17/2016  51  19  09  62  55  14  4`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a "fixed column width" file rather than an ordinary CSV (meaning that the columns are not separated by any single character, but instead have fixed number of characters, with padding spaces).

There is some early work on supporting this in [F# Data in the pull request here](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/pull/803). We'd welcome any help getting this tested - but you'd need to get the soruce code and build F# Data from source (which is just a matter of running the build script though!)

Alternatively, you could probably do some simple pre-processing on the file before reading it as an ordinary CSV file. Looking at the sample file, using a regular expression to replace 1 or more spaces with a comma would produce regular CSV that the CSV provider can consume.